# MongoDB Problems while inserting nested data

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I try to build a database for a giveaway bot using MongoDB. Once a new giveaway is created the bot runs the following code to write the new giveaway into the databank:

```
const {mongoose} = require("mongoose")
const mainSchema = require('../models/mainSchema')

module.exports = {
  async execute(interaction){

  await new mainSchema ({
    guild_id: 1234567890,
    giveaways: [{
      identifier: 34,
      destination: 987654321,                      
    }],                                                                        
  }).save()
}
```

Giveaways should be a nested document in the document with the server's information. My schemas for this looks like this:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const giveawaySchema = new mongoose.Schema({  
    identifier: String,
    destination: String,
    duration: String,
    price: String,
})

const mainSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    guild_id: String,
    log_channel_id: String,
    twitterPreferncesType: String,
    twitterPreferncesFollowing: Boolean,
    giveaways: [giveawaySchema],
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("mainSchema", mainSchema);
module.exports = mongoose.model("giveawaySchema", giveawaySchema);
```

In my Mongo Atlas I have 2 collections `mainSchema` und `giveawaySchema`. If I run this code I only get an entry under 'giveawaySchema' consisting of this:

```
_id: ObjectId(62b4f6374894fb3e7826ca72)
__v:0
```

I don't get any data in the `mainSchema` collection. Does anyone know what is the error? Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your models exports to:

```
const Main = mongoose.model("mainSchema", mainSchema);
const Giveaway = mongoose.model("giveawaySchema", giveawaySchema);

module.exports = { Main, Giveaway }
```

Then, try to create the `Giveaway` entity before the `Main` one, and add that one to the new `Main` document:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Main, Giveaway } = require('../models/mainSchema');

module.exports = {
  async execute(interaction) {
    const newGiveaway = await Giveaway.create({
      identifier: 34,
      destination: 987654321,
    });

    await Main.create({
      guild_id: 1234567890,
      giveaways: [newGiveaway],
    });

    res.status(200).send('Creation completed');
  },
};
```

Answer (score 1):

in your first code you don't have to put mongoose module between brackets (i don't know if it's okay)
and you are importing giveawaySchema not mainSchema
because you are overwriting it you should do this

```js
// module.exports = mongoose.model("mainSchema", mainSchema);
// module.exports = mongoose.model("giveawaySchema", giveawaySchema);
// Wrong you are overwriting on the exports 

// do this instead 
const MainSchema = mongoose.model("mainSchema", mainSchema);
const GiveawaySchema = mongoose.model("giveawaySchema", giveawaySchema);
module.exports = {MainSchema,GiveawaySchema}

// and import it like this 
// const { MainSchema,GiveawaySchema} = require('./<pathOfTheFile>')
```

and if you still have problem just tell me
Good luck ...